# How can I convert a pandas dataframe to Morris dataset for bootstrap

Tags: python, pandas, morris.js

Hi I want to create graphs and tables with Bootstrap using Morris js.

I have to following dataframe:

```
     date          x      y
0    2016-10-03    156   123
1    2016-10-04    220   156
2    2016-10-05    153   152
```

I need to get this in this format:

```
[
{ date: '2016-10-03',x:156, y:123 },
{ date: '2016-10-04',x:220, y:156 },
{ date: '2016-10-05',x:153, y:152 }
]
```

I tried this with to_json but this isn't the correct format and it transforms the dates to ms or datetimes when selecting iso.

Is there a buildin function for this or do I need to write a custom function with for loops to get this format?

Answer (score 2):

use `to_json`

```
print(df.to_json(orient='records'))

[{"date":"2016-10-03","x":156,"y":123},{"date":"2016-10-04","x":220,"y":156},{"date":"2016-10-05","x":153,"y":152}]
```

Comment: This places it in de correct position thanks, however I do still have that the date is transformed to milliseconds. These dates come from mysql DATE(`timestamp`) as date. and using read_sql(). If I set date_format='iso' it prints it like "2016-10-03T00:00:00.000Z"

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should get you the output you're looking for.

```
somelist = []
for n,i in df.iterrows():
    row = {'date': i.date, 'x': i.x, 'y': i.y}
    somelist.append(row)
```